# Evaluate SCSS (SASS) templates in ruby (Rails project)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, sass

I am working on a sort of CMS project where I am leveraging SCSS. I would like to allow the user to specify properties of a stylesheet in a simple way (enable a few color customization), and then generate a CSS file based on SCSS templates, and substitute some variables in the SCSS file using mustache or ERB evaluation.

Basically, I want an ERB file to be rendered as scss file, and then generate a css in my application, upload it to S3, and include in the user's layout. 
If possible I would like to avoid using css.erb files :-)

Comment: Why aren't you just using the **cascading** aspect of Cascading Style Sheets to override the prior CSS style with the user's choices?  For example, generate CSS code within your ERB layout file with the user choices.  What you described above will not scale for lots of users and just sounds error prone.

Comment: Well I really want to investigate a solution using scss, otherwise your comments just sounds like "why are you using scss". What was not really clear in my question is that I want the "administrator" to setup his css using high level parameters (say h1 text color), and then the css is generated and uploaded to S3. This process has nothing to do with website's visitors. I don't need to handle millions of administrators for the moment, even though I don't see why this is not scale.

Comment: I heavily use SCSS, so I'm not saying you shouldn't be using it (for your base styles at least). I'm saying: use the rules of CSS to your advantage rather than trying to reinvent the wheel with a difficult solution.  If you have a CSS template for your CMS and you want to (very easily) override certain aspects of the template, you should be doing so using the rules of CSS such as specificity and the cascading order of the CSS styles.  I'm just trying to make your life easier :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The reason why I am thinking of using using erb + sass is that I want to have a `colors.scss.erb` file, in which a number of colors would be defined. This file would be evaluated using the settings of my user. Then I want to use the `colors.scss` file with others scss files to propagate the values I've used. I understand that this could be achievable using css only but it requires overriding a potentially large number of things in my original css. In a development perspective it looks less scalable than a scss+erb-based solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fact (I am answering my own question). What I am trying to do is really easy. I've made this really simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

#processs.rb file

require 'sass'
result = Sass.compile open(ARGV[0]).read
puts result
```

And it generates css out of a scss file she invoked like this:

```
ruby process.rb myfile.css.scss
```

And this works perfectly. The code documentation [in sass source code](https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/master/lib/sass.rb) helped me to find this out.

Comment: I actually found an simple solution so I answered my own question